# File reading, loops and expressions in Unix using Bourne shell

Tags: shell, loops, unix, expr

I was hoping someone could give me a hand. I'm just starting to learn shell scripting in Unix using the Bourne shell and I've run into a problem.

I'm trying to make a script that takes a file with a series of digits and reads through it with a while loop and checks if the number is larger than 30. If it is, it will increment a counter. At the end it echoes how many times there was a number larger than 30.

The file looks similar to this but larger.

```
0107
0027
0110
```

and this is my code

```
#!/bin/sh
count=0
while read p;do
if ["$p" -ge 30 ]
then
 count=`expr $count + 1`
fi
done < $1
echo " has logged in for more than 30 minutes $count times "
```

In the end I expected this to say you logged in 2 times but instead I get this error for each number in the file. Here is an example.

```
./scriptname: 4: ./scriptname: [0107: not found
```

Anyway I was thinking that perhaps it wasn't treating the integers as integers but instead as strings. Maybe I didn't format my "if" properly but I'm not sure what's wrong; that's why I've come here.

Comment: Oh dear ive been beating myself up on this for a while and the problem was so silly, thank you so much!

Comment: This is the same problem as caused the trouble in [Bash script — syntax to compare strings as integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021755/bash-script-syntax-to-compare-strings-as-integers) and a large number of other problems.  The command name needs to be kept separate from its arguments, and `[` is a command (it is usually a shell built-in, but there's often also a binary program that implements more or less the same functionality in `/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/[` or both).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a single space to your `if` like

```
if [ "$p" -ge 30 ]
```

The reasons for this should become clear if you

```
$ type [
```

and

```
$ which [
```

Answer (score 0):

You need space after open square bracket like:

```
if [ "$p" -ge 30 ]
    ^
```